# Обработка нажатия клавиши в другом фрагменте

Tags: java, android

У меня есть три фрагмента из одного контейнера и один фрагмент Choose  из другого контейнера.  Я хочу чтобы обработчик нажатия кнопки butYes  из класса фрагмента Choose был доступен для другого фрагмента.

Класс фрагмента Choose

```
public class Choose extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choose, container, false);
    Button butYes = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.butYes);
    butYes.setOnClickListener(onclik);
    return v;
}

View.OnClickListener onclik = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
};
```

Comment: правильно это делать через интерфэйс и активити. Вот урок: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/176-urok-106-android-3-fragments-vzaimodejstvie-s-activity.html

Comment: Я уже пробовал через интерфейс и предопределенный метод в активити, получилось сделать метод который работает только с одним конкретным классом фрагмента, а у меня много фрагментов.Дело в том что в каждом фрагменте есть метод наследованный от класса БД, и получается что этот метод связан с view класса конкретного фрагмента.

Comment: а в чем именно сложность? передавайте id целевого фрагмента через `interface`, а сами фрагменты храните в массиве

Comment: А фрагменты нужно находить с помощью метода findFragmentById в предопределенном методе интерфейса? Просто у меня есть метод deleteRow() который должен использоваться именно в классе конкретного фрагмента, если использовать его из другого класса будет ошибка

Comment: наверное лучше массив создать, чтобы по id в массиве искать. Но можно и `findFragmentById`. Ошибку можно экранировать `try/catch` или проверкой `instanceOf`. Хотя вообще при правильной организации кода ее быть не должно. В чем ваша сложность я так и не понял)

Comment: При использовании массивов с фрагментами, я не смогу обратится к методу, где находится deleteRow() в фрагменте, потому что у классов фрагментов разные типы.

Comment: навскидку: `if (fragments.get(id) instanceOf NeededFragment) ((NeededFragment) fragments.get(id)).deleteRow()`

Comment: читал где-то, что `instanceOf` тратят много памяти, поэтому ими лучше не злоупотреблять. Но иногда можно. Логику приложения не знаю, возможно есть методы проще.

Comment: В классе Choose в обработчике, должно задаваться  id в предопределенный метод из активити OnSelectedButtonListener listener = (OnSelectedButtonListener) getActivity();
listener.onButtonSelected(id); Но как программе узнать какое id должно быть? Можно ли сделать так ,чтобы активити узнавал какой фрагмент находится в контейнере и получал его id?

Comment: `container.getChildAt(0).getId()`?

Comment: Пожалуйста можете подробнее написать как использовать container.getChildAt(0).getId(), если можно с примером, буду признателен.

Comment: я не знаю вашей реализации и не знаю, как вы хотите его использовать) метод позволяет получить id фрагмента, который добавлен в контейнер. Сравните его через `instanceOf` с нужным типом, приведите и вызовите нужную функцию